# If Hashem loves Am Yisrael, why did He intend to destroy them?

Tags: tanach, reward-punishment, genocide

In parshat Ki Tissa, Hashem tells Moshe that He wants to destroy Am Yisrael and rebuild the nation using Moshe. Similarly in parshat Shlach. I can understand the concept of Hashem inflicting punishment as discipline but what rationale would justify a genocide of the people you allegedly love?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing us your interesting question. I must admit i never thought of that angle before. If you haven't already, you might want to check out our [tour] to familiarize yourself with the site, so that you can God willing enjoy a long and productive stay here. :)

Comment: maybe it means that's what they deserve

Answer (score 2):

[Shemos 32:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9893#showrashi=true)

> וְעַתָּה הַנִּיחָה לִּי וְיִחַר אַפִּי בָהֶם וַאֲכַלֵּם וְאֶעֱשֶׂה
>   אוֹתְךָ לְגוֹי גָּדוֹל:
>
> 10 Now leave Me alone, and My anger will be kindled against them so
>   that I will annihilate them, and I will make you into a great nation."

Rashi

> הניחה לי: עדיין לא שמענו, שהתפלל משה עליהם, והוא אומר הניחה לי, אלא
>   כאן פתח לו פתח והודיעו, שהדבר תלוי בו, שאם יתפלל עליהם לא יכלם
>
> leave Me alone: [It is unclear why God is saying this-which implies
>   that Moses has made a demand-since] we have not yet heard that Moses
>   prayed for them, and yet He [God] said, “Leave Me alone” ? But here,
>   He opened a door for him and informed him that the matter [indeed]
>   depended upon him [Moses], that if he [Moses] would pray for them, He
>   [God] would not destroy them. [Therefore, God implores Moses to leave
>   Him alone so that He can destroy Israel.] -[from Exod. Rabbah 42:9]

This is the same as the question about the mabul of Noach. It is also similar to the destruction of S'dom. There are times that no matter how much a child is loved, he has gone so far as to totally destroy his existence. Bnai Yisrael had put themselves in the position of eventually destroying the world. They had acted in a way that would make them like Yishmael to Avraham or Esav to Yitzchak. Hashem could not allow this to continue.

Consider also the situation of parents who have a ben sorer umore. They had to bring their son to judgment. It is a tragedy and one of the utmost sadness, but it must be done.

The world only exists because of the three pillars of Torah, Avodah, and Gemilus Cahsadim.  Bnei Yisroel were in the process of destroying these pillars. It was the choice between them and the world.

As we see in Rashi this was actually Hashem requesting Moshe to intervene to prevent the destruction. Noach is castigated for not begging Hashem to save the world (as Avraham did for S'dom). Moshe did not make the mistake that Noach did, but did step forward (as Hashem had wanted) to save them.

Rav Hirsch explains similarly that the language used הַנִּיחָה לִּי makes the command "hypothetical" and that Hashem is giving Moshe the choice to intercede or not. Also, it is not that this is because of Hashem's anger but that this is the inevitable reaction to the action that they did (just as jumping off a cliff leads to falling to death). Additionally, it is not because of Moshe that he will be the start of the new people, but that Hashem will still keep the promise to the Avos in any case (through Moshe).

> So the meaning is: if you were to leave it to me, i.e., if you do not
>   intervene and intercede, if the people are left to themselves, if
>   nothing comes forward out of the people, and in the people, to
>   mitigate and help them over the apostasy, there is no alternative but
>   that they will be destroyed. But My purpose and My promise that it
>   will be realized through Israel will not be lost; for you still remain
>   and you will I make into a second Avraham, and the "great nation" that
>   I promised him will I raise afresh from you, who are also Avraham's
>   seed.